# FORTRAN, why do I have inf when reading extremely big numbers?

Tags: fortran

```
open(10,file='datad.dat',status='old')

do i=1,1484
read(10,99)d(i,:)
99 format(10(e16.12))
end do
```

This is my code to read datad.dat.File is huge,will post just first row:

```
   2.1762368e+13             0.0             0.0             0.0   1.0123726e-01  1.7723948e+149   1.0671934e+06  1.5929603e+104   4.3220965e+48   7.2446595e+16
```

But when I execute code I got:

```
  2.17623686E+13   0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000      0.101237260             Infinity   1067193.38             Infinity         Infinity   7.24465978E+16
```

I have compiled FORTRAN code with gfortran.Why do I have infinity,is there limitation regarding the exponent?How can I check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how you've declared d and which compiler you're using.

On GFortran, the limit is HUGE(0.0E0) for reals and HUGE(0D0) for double precision.  This roughly comes up to 1E38 for real and 1D308 for DP.

At a guess, you've declared d as real so anything over 1E38 would be infinity.

Comment: Yes,I have declared d as real,although my machine is 64-bit.

Comment: The fact you have a 64-bit machine dors not change anything. It just affects sizes of memory addresses.

Comment: Perhaps the comment about "On a 32-bit machine" is a little misleading?

Comment: Yes - I forgot that reals on 64 bit machines are 32 bits.  I've change it accordingly.